# upload big files with html5 uploader

Tags: html, upload, wamp

My problem is that i need to upload big videos files, but not that big. like 100~500mb. videos with 70mb i can do it. when i try to upload a large file, firefox crashes and closes. the same happen with chrome. I'm using html5uploader.js.

> /*
>   *   Upload files to the server using HTML 5 Drag and drop the folders on your local computer
>   *   Tested on: Mozilla Firefox 3.6.12, Google Chrome 7.0.517.41, Safari 5.0.2, WebKit r70732
>   *   The current version does not work on: Opera 10.63, Opera 11 alpha, IE 6+.
>   */

function uploader(place, status, targetPHP, show) {

```
// Upload image files
upload = function(file) {
      if((file.type == 'image/jpeg' || file.type == 'audio/mpeg' || file.type =='image/png' || file.type == 'image/bmp' || file.type == 'image/gif')){
            alert('Arquivo não permitido.');
            return false;
      }

      // Firefox 3.6, Chrome 6, WebKit
    if(window.FileReader) { 

        // Once the process of reading file
        this.loadEnd = function() {
            bin = reader.result;                
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', targetPHP+'?up=true', true);
            var boundary = 'xxxxxxxxx';
            var body = '--' + boundary + "\r\n";
```

//              body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='upload'; filename='" + file.name + "'\r\n";
                body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='upload'; filename='" + encodeURI(file.name) + "'\r\n";
                body += "Content-Type: " + file.type + "\r\n\r\n";
                body += bin + "\r\n";
                body += '--' + boundary + '--';
                xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
                // Firefox 3.6 provides a feature sendAsBinary ()
                if(xhr.sendAsBinary != null) { 
                    xhr.sendAsBinary(body); 
                // Chrome 7 sends data but you must use the base64_decode on the PHP side
                } else { 
                    xhr.open('POST', targetPHP+'?up=true&base64=true', true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-FILENAME', file.name);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-SIZE', file.size);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-TYPE', file.type);
                    xhr.send(window.btoa(bin));
                }
                if (show) {
                    var newFile  = document.createElement('div');
                    tamanho = (((file.size)/1024)/1024);
                    tamanhoMB = tamanho.toFixed(2);
                    newFile.innerHTML = 'Nome do arquivo: ' + file.name+ ' | Tamanho: '+tamanhoMB+' MB';
                    document.getElementById(show).appendChild(newFile);
                }
                if (status) {
                    document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = 'Upload concluído! Arraste o próximo arquivo.';
                }
            };

```
        // Loading errors
        this.loadError = function(event) {
            switch(event.target.error.code) {
                case event.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                    document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = '<h4>Arquivo não encontrado!</h4>';
                break;
                case event.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
                    document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = '<h4>Arquivo não legível!</h4>';
                break;
                case event.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
                break; 
                default:
                    document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = '<h4>Erro de leitura.</h4>';
            }   
        };

        // Reading Progress
        this.loadProgress = function(event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                var percentage = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total);
                document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = '<h4>Carregando... '+percentage+'%</h4>';
            }               
        };

        // Preview images
        this.previewNow = function(event) { 
            bin = preview.result;
            var img = document.createElement("img"); 
            img.className = 'addedIMG';
            img.file = file;   
            img.src = bin;
            document.getElementById(show).appendChild(img);
        };

    reader = new FileReader();
    // Firefox 3.6, WebKit
    if(reader.addEventListener) { 
        reader.addEventListener('loadend', this.loadEnd, false);
        if (status != null) 
        {
            reader.addEventListener('error', this.loadError, false);
            reader.addEventListener('progress', this.loadProgress, false);
        }

    // Chrome 7
    } else { 
        reader.onloadend = this.loadEnd;
        if (status != null) 
        {
            reader.onerror = this.loadError;
            reader.onprogress = this.loadProgress;
        }
    }
    var preview = new FileReader();
    // Firefox 3.6, WebKit
    if(preview.addEventListener) { 
        preview.addEventListener('loadend', this.previewNow, false);
    // Chrome 7 
    } else { 
        preview.onloadend = this.previewNow;
    }

    // The function that starts reading the file as a binary string
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

    // Preview uploaded files
    if (show) {
        preview.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    // Safari 5 does not support FileReader
    } else {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', targetPHP+'?up=true', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-FILENAME', file.name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-SIZE', file.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-TYPE', file.type);
        xhr.send(file); 

        if (status) {
            document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = '100% carregado';
        }
        if (show) {
            var newFile  = document.createElement('div');
            newFile.innerHTML = file.name+' (Tamanho: '+file.size+' Bytes)';
            document.getElementById(show).appendChild(newFile);
        }   
    }               
};

// Function drop file
this.drop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dt = event.dataTransfer;
    var files = dt.files;
        if (files.length<=2){
            for (var i = 0; i<files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                upload(file);
            }
        }else{
            alert('Limite de upload excedido! Máximo permitido: dois arquivos.');
        }
};

// The inclusion of the event listeners (DragOver and drop)

this.uploadPlace =  document.getElementById(place);
this.uploadPlace.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    event.preventDefault();
}, true);
this.uploadPlace.addEventListener("drop", this.drop, false);
```

}

i read a lot of questions and posts with a similar problem, but nothing seems to work here. i dont know what else i can do. i change the variables to these values both on wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini, wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin\php.ini and wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\phpForApache.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize -> 1024mb, 
post_max_size -> 1024mb, 
max_execution_time -> 600, 
max_input_time -> 600,
memory_limit -> 2048mb.
```

Restart wamp, didnt work. On wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf i put the following:

`<Directory "D:\wamp\www\projec">
    LimitRequestBody 102400
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>`

Also didnt work. anyone has a solution or idea to save me? I really appreciate. Thanks.